# CSS Header Image Alignment

Tags: css, image, browser, header, alignment

I will like to seek help in CSS regarding header image alignment for a subreddit page of mine. Here's the current code for the header image and overlay, do ignore the z-index and what not:

```
  #header {
  z-index: 2147483647;
  height: 260px;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -90px 0 0 rgba(21, 27, 33, .6);
  background: url(%%overlay%%) fixed center/auto auto, linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(39, 161, 227, .65), rgba(231, 35, 42, .65)), url(%%header%%) 0 0/cover
```

From this code, my header image will align to the left edge, even when I resize my browser or view on mobile. I hope to change the alignment such that it will centralise the header image even when I resize browser or view on mobile.

Here's another template whereby the header image gives the result I am looking for:

```
#header {
border: 0;
height: 200px;
background-color: #000000;
background-image: url(%%banner1%%);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: center;
}
#header #header-img { display: none; }
@media (max-width: 1800px) {
    #header {
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
```

I'm really weak in this and I was unable to project them over to get the same results, will appreciate if anyone can help me out with this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding margin:auto to your #header style like so

#header {
      margin:auto;
      ....
   }

Comment: Hi richard, thanks for the reply!

I have tried what you have suggested,

#header {margin:auto;
      z-index: 2147483647;
      height: 260px;
      border: 0;
      box-shadow: inset 0 -90px 0 0 rgba(21, 27, 33, .6);
      background: url(%%overlay%%) fixed center/auto auto, linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(39, 161, 227, .65), rgba(231, 35, 42, .65)), url(%%header%%) 0 0/cover

It did not seem to work though

Comment: Could you add the html layout and explain how exactly the header image needs to be centered. I mean if it the center of the page or centered with respect to some div

Comment: Hello again Richard, thanks for the help, I have managed to port part of the code across the template, and they are not working as desired :D